# Does HDFS support INotify with file open event?

Tags: hdfs

Does HDFS support INotify with file open event? From document it seems that hdfs inotify only support append, close, create ... not include file open, while linux inotify supports IN_OPEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not. The HDFS INotify feature is based off of the EditLog, which only contains write transactions. Thus INotify will only be aware of modifications to the namespace, not accesses.

Source: [HDFS-6634](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6634), the JIRA that originally added this feature.